# JDBC SQL Connection

Tags: mysql, jdbc, packet

I am trying to use JDBC to connect to a mysql database on our school's server. Here is my code:

```
    try
    {
      // Step 1: Load the JDBC driver. 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        System.out.println(1);


      // Step 2: Establish the connection to the database. 
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://csci.lakeforest.edu:3306/csci427_spring11";

        System.out.println(2);

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"username","password");  

        System.out.println(3);

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement (); // Create statement

        System.out.println(2);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
      System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
```

The 1 and 2 are printing, but then I get this error:

**Got an exception! 
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I had this very same problem and it was the driver I was using.  See about updating/finding a new jar file for your MySql driver.  I can't remember exactly what I did to solve this, but I believe it has everything to do with drivers and server configuration, not your code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I downloaded the jar file from the mysql website just a few days ago, so I think it is up to date. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

That usually means:

1. The server is down
2. The name of the server is wrong
3. The port number is wrong

Comment: 4. A firewall is blocking connections

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. The server name is correct, the server is up, and I am using the default port number 3306.

Comment: Hi @Balus, Thanks for the response. Can you tell me how to check if a firewall is blocking connections and how to prevent this? Thank you.

Comment: @meanie: Try to telnet on the server on that port. If you get a connection, then it's the firewall. If the connection hangs for two minutes and you get an error after that, it's the firewall. Ask your local sysadmin for help.